# Efficient way to store many resulting dataframes that have been split from a larger one

Tags: python, loops, pandas, vector, dataframe

I have a very large pandas dataframe that I'm splitting into many smaller ones based on values in two particular columns. Is there a more efficient way to store these dataframes that doesn't involve a loop? This is what I have right now:

```
df_list=[]
grouped=df.groupby(['column1', 'column2'], as_index = False)
for l,g in grouped:
    df_list.append(g)
```

There are over 700,000 rows in the original df and I'm guessing over 100,000 resulting dataframes. The method I'm using at the moment takes around 5 minutes. I'm looking for a way to store the dataframes that doesn't involve a loop.

Comment: Why do you need to store them? Can't you just refer to the groups?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that and I can't figure it out from the groupby documentation. Could you give me an example?

Comment: from the groupby object it has the attribute [`.groups`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.groups.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.groups) this returns a dict of groupName->labels you can then call [`.get_group`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.get_group.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.get_group) and pass the group name

Comment: Got it working, thanks!